# UIButtons receiving touch events when added directly to scrollview but not indirectly

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton, subview

I have 10 UIButtons stacked side to side in my app , and the total dimensions of the buttons are 640x96.

If I add these buttons **directly** to the UIScrollView, they register touch events and are scrollable.

But if I try to add them to a plain UIView, then add that UIView to the scrollview, they dont work.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIView *fview = [[UIView alloc] init];
fview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 96);
fview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[fview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[_sv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(64*i, 0, 64, 96);
        [button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [fview addSubview:button];
}
[_sv addSubview:fview];
_sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 96);
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was writing the question I fixed the problem :D

All I had to do was to **set the frame of the UIView** before I set the scrollview's contentsize.

In my case:

```
[_sv addSubview:fview];
fview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 96); // Added line
_sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 96);
```

Hope this helps!